# How to uninstall Ubuntu 16.04 running alongside Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

After installing Ubuntu on my system, I can't access my Windows 10 OS. The system boots Ubuntu without providing a choice to boot into Windows. Is there a way I can have both or must I uninstall Ubuntu in order to access Windows?

Comment: When you installed it, what option did you choose for disk partitioning?  Also, please add the output of typing `sudo fdisk -l` in terminal to your question.

Comment: Please check older questions for answers to your issue before posting new question. This question gets asked like every other day

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 10 with UEFI](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi)

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite grub2 by repairing Windows bootloader from Windows 10 install DVD.

Open Command Line on Windows and type `bootsect /nt60 sys /mbr`
This will write Windows bootloader on MBR.

Then from Windows you can remove Ubuntu (and swap/home) partition.